# I just want to do validation by using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

im new to add ajax and jqquery to codeigniter 
When i run the below code i didnt return anything 
I dont know whether url in ajax is properly working or not

**Controller**

```
function test()
{       
  $email=$this->input->post('email');
  $query=mysql_query("select * from info  where email='$email'");
  $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($row==0)
  {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Available</span>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Not Available Choose another one..</span>";
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ajaxchecker/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#email").keyup(function() {
          var email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajaxsample/check",
              data: "email="+ email ,
              success: function(html){
                $("#disp").html(html);
              }
            });
          return false;
        });
      })       
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Username Check using Ajax/php.mysql</h3>
    <form method="post">
      Username: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br /><br />
      <div id="disp"></div><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your error ? (You can find it in the developer tool). Another point I'm not sur that the url is working, following some framework architecture.

Comment: what is /ajaxsample/check in
url: "http://localhost/sample/index.php/ajaxsample/check" ???

Comment: what i actually want is if the email id exist in db it should show me 'Not available'

Comment: Get the email value via post. rather than $this->input->post('email'); Also properly specify the file name and path to the ajax file.

Comment: ajaxsample/check() function where that data have to go for process sharma

Comment: @SharmaDhananjay I guess that the route is `ajaxsample/check` but I'm not sur. Waiting for the result from dev tool.

Comment: u r using CI and not follwing the MVC format

Comment: Not like that Mohit it just the sample

Comment: I've checked your edit. You can [try debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391075/codeigniter-get-all-declared-routes) by printing routes. You must check in your browser developer tools to check where the problem come from.

Comment: have you googled abut it

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check if the $("#email").keyup(function() is working, try to put an alert() and write something in the email input to verify you are entering the function.

Second, try to check if you are receiving the email via Post in your controller. If you don't have problem with that...

Try to change your controller to this:

```
    function test()
{       
  $email=$this->input->post('email');
  $query=mysql_query("select * from info  where email='$email'");
  $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($row==0)
  {
    $text =  "<span style='color:green;'>Available</span>";
  }
  else
  {
    $text = "<span style='color:red;'>Not Available Choose another one..</span>";
  }

  $this->output->set_output($text);
}
```

And your view to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ajaxchecker/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#email").keyup(function() {
          var email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo site_url('ajaxsample/check'); ?>",
              data: {email:email} ,
              dataType: "html",
              success: function(html){
                $("#disp").html(html);
              }
            });
          return false;
        });
      })       
    </script>
```

Remeber to load the url_helper to use site_url() and base_url().
If you still have problems add this to your ajax.

```
success: function(html){
 $("#disp").html(html);
},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ajaxchecker/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").keyup(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/ajaxsample/test",
    data: {'email':email},
    success: function(html){
    $("#disp").html(html);
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
    })       
    </script>
```

in Controller

```
 function test()
    {       
      $email=$this->input->post('email');
      $query=$this->db->query("select * from info  where email like '%".$email."'%");
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
        echo "<span style='color:green;'>Available</span>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<span style='color:red;'>Not Available Choose another one..</span>";
      }
    }
```