# How to get Codeigniter all routes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

This question is not a duplicate of [codeigniter get all declared routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391075/codeigniter-get-all-declared-routes)

I have to get all my CodeIgniter framework routes for all the controllers. I have not defined any routing under routes.php, I am just using the route like

`https://domain/controller/action`

Now I want to get my all route like

```
https://domain/user/login

https://domain/user/logout
```

and so on...

Is there any way to get my all routes?

I hope you understand what I want to say!

Comment: As per my understanding you want to read all your application controller action right?

Comment: @B.K right Can you please help me to achieve this ..??

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I have found a way to get all routes from a particular controller, trying something which gives me all routes from all controller

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am not wrong. You want to fetch all methods of given class and/or all classes along with their methods in given controller directory.

This way you will be having all available routes for the `application/controllers/User.php say`

You can achieve the same by doing as follow.

You can use Codeigniter Library named `List.php` from source code at [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/Thedijje/2fca01ac8f737fa24529134775c4a029#file-list_files-php)

You can use this library to list all controllers and methods.

### Usage

You can fetch controllers list as below

```
function index()
{
        //  Fetch list of controllers 

        $endpoints  =   array_keys($this->lists->getControllers());

        print_r($endpoints);


}
```

You can fetch list of methods inside any given controllers as below:

```
function list_routes($endpoint='')
{
        if($endpoint=='')
            {
                die('Error');
            }

            $endpoint =     ucfirst($endpoint);
            $methods  =     $this->lists->getControllers();

            print_r($methods);
}
```

If you want to change the default folder from `/controllers/` to anything else, you can either modify List.php function to extend and pass the dynamic parameter to `setControllers` function at

```
foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'YOUR_FOLDER_HERE') as $controller) {
    ###
}
```

I am using the Above solution to fetch and automate some API documentation where I fetch all endpoints and routes along with comments to display in our developer panel.

Please feel free to reach me if having any doubts or question regarding the same.

Comment: Yes, It's working perfect for Normal CI But I am using CI HMVC So it's not working as I want.
So I did some modification in your code and it's working me for most of the cases but  there is one problem if I am extended MX_Controller in place of CI_controller its break and giving fatal error  'Cannot declare class CI, because the name is already in use'

Comment: he is throwing error on 
$this->CI->load->file($subdircontroller);
Is there any way to load file extending MX_Controller ?